# Why does my Scheme function return an error "application: not a procedure"?

Tags: list, scheme

I want to get the second value of '(a b c) and I don't want to use cadr.
I can get the right answer:

```
(car (cdr '(a b c)))

'b
```

But when I built the function:

```
(define test (lambda (list) (car (cdr (list)))))

(test '(a b c))
```

I get the following error:

```
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(a b c)
  arguments...: [none]
```

I really don't know what's this error means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Racket PLAI Application not a Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/racket-plai-application-not-a-procedure)

Comment: In the future, if you have a specific error message, you can often find results in Stack Overflow by searching for that specific error message (and perhaps the language name).  For instance, searching for [application: not a procedure scheme is:question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=application%3A+not+a+procedure+scheme+is%3Aquestion) turns up 121 results.  Also, there's no need to include "Scheme" in the title of the question;  including it in the tags is sufficient for people looking for Scheme questions to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are incorrect parentheses in your code, surrounding the `list` parameter - in Scheme this: `(f)` means "apply the `f` function with no arguments", so in your code this: `(list)` is trying to invoke the `list` parameter as if it were a function, which is not, raising an error.

Also notice that it's a bad idea to call `list` the parameter, there's already a built-in procedure with that name; that's why I renamed it to `lst`. This should fix it:

```
(define test
  (lambda (lst)
    (car (cdr lst))))

(test '(a b c))
=> b
```

Comment: Other common metasyntactic names for a list include `xs` and `ls`. The former is common for the `x` in `xs` kind of thinking.