# Return the second element for every element in a list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Let's say we have this list `'( (4 (1 2))  (5 (5 5)) (7 (3 1)) (1 (2 3)))`

I am trying to write smth in Scheme  in order to get the second element for every element in the list.. So the result will look like `'( (1 2) (5 5) (3 1) (2 3))`

I have this code so far..

```
(define (second  list1)
  (if (null? (cdr list1))
      (cdr (car list1))
      ((cdr (car list1))(second (cdr list1)))))
```

Comment: whats wrong with the code?

Comment: I get this..application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '((3 1))
  arguments...:
   '((2 3))

Comment: Format the code in a reasonable way (i.e no lines cantaining only parens) and the problem will be easier to spot.

Comment: There's an answer that tell you how to do this, but the actual error your're getting is addressed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19022704/1281433).

Comment: possible duplicate of [“application: not a procedure” in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19022704/1281433).  That question won't tell how to `map` `cadr` over a list, but the _specific programming question_ here is not how to do that, but rather "Why is there an application: not a procedure …" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution:

```
(define (seconds lst)
  (map cadr lst))
```

In general, when you want to transform every element of a list, `map` is the way to go.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot chris!! I have so much to learn about Scheme

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._map%29%29) the built-in function [`second`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._second%29%29) onto the list `lst`:

```
(map second lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you lack an operator, perhaps `cons`. If you look at the consequent:

```
((cdr (car list1))(second (cdr list1)))
```

So Scheme expects (cdr (car list)) to be a procedure since it's in operator position in the form, but since it isn't you get an error. In addition `(cdr (car x))` == `cdar` wont take the second element in every element but the tail of each element. `cadar` is what you're lookig for.

```
(define (second  list1)00+
  (if (null? (cdr list1))
      (cons (cadar list1) '())
      (cons (cadar list1) (second (cdr list1)))))
```

It will fail for the empty list. To fix this you let the consequemt take care of every element and the base case only to stop:

```
(define (second  list1)
  (if (null? list1)
      '()
      (cons (cadar list1) (second (cdr list1)))))
```

The result for a list will be the same. There is a procedure called map. It supports several list arguments, but the implementation for one is:

```
(define (map fun lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (fun (car lst)) (map fun (cdr lst)))))
```

Looks familiar? Both make a list based on each element, but `map` is generic. Thus we should try to make `(fun (car lst))` do the same as `(cadar lst)`.

```
(define (second lst)
  (map cadr lst)) ; (cadr (car x)) == (cadar x)
```

There you have it. [Chris beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599666/1565698), but I'd like to comment one of the other answers that uses the abbreviation `second`. It's defined in racket/base and the library SRFI-1, but it's not mentioned in the last Scheme reports. I.e. some implementations might require an extra library to be imported for it to work.

Comment: ...and one of the other other answers also has this, but also uses `cadr` like your solution did, rather than the synonym `second`, but your post seemed to have overlooked that, even though it was the fastest gun in the west and was the accepted answer. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You are fast :-) , but me commenting on a different answer was to mention you cannot expect every make to have `second` defined.