# Scheme void error?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to scheme and i have wrote a small program that takes atoms from list based on start and end indices.

```
(define counter 0)
(define (sub x y a_list) 
  (cond
    ((null? a_list) '())
    ((and (>= counter x) (< counter y)) (cons x (sub x y (cdr a_list))))
    (else((set! counter (+ counter 1)) (sub x y (cdr a_list))))
  ))
```

I don't see any problem with this code but when i execute it for example:

```
(sub 1 3 '(X G H S E))
```

I get the following error:

```
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received (void)
```

Comment: Double parenthesis around your `set!`, but the result is wrong.

Comment: it should be double parenthesis, cause otherwise i can't put tow statements inside else.

Comment: can you please re-write the else statement because i have tired many things with the parenthesis before and non worked for me

Comment: possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
(define (sub x y lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (counter 0))
    (cond
      ((null? lst) 
       '())
      ((and (>= counter x) (< counter y)) 
       (cons (car lst) (loop (cdr lst) (+ 1 counter))))
      (else 
       (loop (cdr lst) (+ 1 counter))))))
```

- no global variable, counter is local here
- you cons x, but you must cons (car lst)

Your code, rewritten, would be

```
(define counter 0)

(define (sub x y a_list) 
  (cond
    ((null? a_list) 
     '())
    ((and (>= counter x) (< counter y)) 
     (begin
       (set! counter (+ counter 1)) 
       (cons (car a_list) (sub x y (cdr a_list)))))
    (else
     (begin
       (set! counter (+ counter 1)) 
       (sub x y (cdr a_list))))))
```

but the second execution would fail because the counter is not reset to 0:

```
(sub 1 3 '(X G H S E))
=> '(G H)
(sub 1 3 '(X G H S E))
=> '()
```

Regarding your initial question:

1. to group forms in a place where only one form is allowed (`if` comes to mind), use `begin` (see the excellent Racket help for details)
2. `((f x ...) y ...)` first evaluates `(f x ...)`, which should return a procedure `p`; then it evaluates `(p y ...)`. In your case, `f` was `set!`, which always evaluates to `(void)`, so this was evaluated as `((void) y ...)`. Hence the error message.

**EDIT**

Illustrating @WorBlux's idea without a counter:

```
(define (sub x y lst)
  (cond
    ((or (null? lst) (<= y 0))
     '())
    ((> x 0)
     (sub (- x 1) (- y 1) (cdr lst)))
    (else
     (cons (car lst) (sub (- x 1) (- y 1) (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: I have tired your re-written code but still produce the same erorr, i am using dr.racet advance student so i don't know if that is the problem. i had to wrap the set with another parenthesis because it wouldn't compile otherwise.

Comment: Ok, modified. You *really* should state in your question what language you use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a counter in this problem just think about the patteren of recursion a little more

(sub x y L) is equivalent to (sub (? x) (? y) (cdr L)) where x is greater than zero, and is equivalent to (? (? L) (sub x (? y) (cdr L))) where x is 0 but y is positive and equivalent to the empty list where y is less than zero.