# Application not a procedure (Scheme map procedure)

Tags: dictionary, scheme, lambda, r5rs

I am attempting to write my own simplified map procedure in R5RS. In short, it takes a procedure and two lists, and returns a list with the results of the procedure called on every pair of objects in the two argument lists, until either is empty.

This works fine for arithmetic operators, such as:

```
(map2-rec + '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
```

However, when I attempt to pass an anonymous lambda function (the return value of my both? procedure) which returns either #t or #f, this does not work.

```
(define (map2-rec proc items1 items2)
  (if (or (null? items1) (null? items2))
      '()
      (cons (proc (car items1) (car items2))
            (map2-rec proc (cdr items1) (cdr items2)))))


(define (both? proc)
  (lambda (item1 item2)
    ((if (and (proc item1) (proc item2))
         #t
         #f))))
```

The specific error I am receiving in DrRacket is:

```
application: not a procedure;  
expected a procedure that can be
applied to arguments   
given: #t   
arguments...: [none]
```

If someone could tell me how I can correct this error, I'd be very happy. I cannot understand why this code fails myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)  This problem generally occurs when you've got an extra set of parenthesis (in this case, it's at `((if … #t #f))`, so that the result of the `(if … #t #f)` (in this case `#t`) is being called as a procedure (but it's not a procedure).

Comment: Also, `(and … …)` is already returning a boolean;  `(if test #t #f)` is equivalent to `test`.  You should use `(define (both? proc) (lambda (item1 item2) (and (proc item1) (proc item2))))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor `and` does not necessarily return a boolean (for example: `(and 1 2)`) - although it'll work just fine with OP's example, but if for some reason `both?` _must_ return exclusively `#t` or `#f`, it's ok to use `if`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Good point!  Yes, if OP Henrik definitely needs a `#t` or `#f`, then `(if … #t #f)` is the way to go.  I seem to recall most Schemes being a bit stricter about the "anything that's not false (`#f` in Scheme, and `()` in many other Lisps) is true," so I only tend to expect the "`and` returns false or the value of the last argument" behavior in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an extra (and erroneous) pair of parentheses in `both?`, surrounding the `if` expression. This should fix it:

```
(define (both? proc)
  (lambda (item1 item2)
    (if (and (proc item1) (proc item2))
        #t
        #f)))
```

Now your procedure works as expected:

```
(map2-rec + '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(2 4 6)
(map2-rec (both? even?) '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(#f #t #f)
```

Comment: Wow, that's it! Thank you so much. I'll accept the answer once the timer's ready :)

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold no problem, it was my pleasure :)

Comment: @Henrik Óscar's answer is right, of course, but you can (and should) do away with the `if` altogether, and just return `(and (proc item1) (proc item2))` directly.