# Scheme - application: not a procedure error

Tags: scheme, racket, non-procedure-application

I'm coding a function in scheme but I'm getting a "application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments" error. I assume that I haven't used the conditional statements correctly:

```
(define find-allocations
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (cons ((if (<=(get-property (car l) 'capacity) n)
               (cons (car l) (find-allocations (- n (get-property (car l) 'capacity)) (cdr l)))
               '()))
          (if (<=(get-property (car l) 'capacity) n)
              (cons (car l) (find-allocations (n (cdr l))))
              '())))))
```

If anyone can point out my error that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application not a procedure (Scheme map procedure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855124/application-not-a-procedure-scheme-map-procedure)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)

Comment: This doesn't show a lot of research effort;  a Google search for [`site:stackoverflow.com "application: not a procedure"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22Scheme+-+application%3A+not+a+procedure+error%22) turns up *lots* of results on Stack Overflow, and they're all about misplaced parentheses.  Searching for exact error messages is a good practice to get into.  Also, doesn't Racket's editor highlights *where* the problem is, as shown in the duplicate that I linked to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define find-allocations
  (lambda (n l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (cons (if (<= (get-property (car l) 'capacity) n)
                  (cons (car l) (find-allocations (- n (get-property (car l) 'capacity)) (cdr l)))
                  '())
              (if (<= (get-property (car l) 'capacity) n)
                  (cons (car l) (find-allocations n (cdr l)))
                  '())))))
```

It's a very common mistake when learning Scheme: writing unnecessary parentheses! Remember: in Scheme a pair of `()` means *function application*, so when you write something - anything like this: `(f)`, Scheme tries to apply `f` as if it were a procedure, in your code you had a couple of places where this was happening:

```
((if (<=(get-property (car l) 'capacity) n) ; see the extra, wrong ( at the beginning

(find-allocations (n (cdr l)))) ; n is not a function, that ( is also mistaken
```

Comment: Simple matter of removing parenthesis, much appreciated still.

Comment: @user3352349 yep :) but it's important that you understand _why_ they were misplaced!