# Writing a function that takes a function as an argument in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

This is a hw assignment that requires me to write a scheme function that takes a function(with two params) and a list as parameters, then returns a list where each consecutive pair of the elements of the list is replaced by the value of the function applied to these two elements.

For example - If the list has an odd number of elements, the last element is ignored. For example, (apply-to-pairs (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(3 9 5 8 2 4 7)) should return (12 13 6).

so far what I have got is:

```
(define (fn-name fn l)
  (if (null? (cdr l))null
      (cons 
        (fn((car l)(car (cdr l)))
         (fn-name fn (cdr l))))))
```

However, im getting this error in Racket(DrRacket):

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 3
  arguments...:
   9
```

... and it highlights `fn((car lst)(car (cdr lst)))`. I'm trying to find out how to handle the function parameter. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A Google search for [`"application: not a procedure" site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22application%3A+not+a+procedure%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) turns up lots of results that explain this for you: you've got extra parens.  `(fn ((car l) (car (cdr l))))` should be `(fn (car l) (car (cdr l)))`.  Generally, when you encounter an error, you'll do well to search for the exact error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already did you just apply `fn` like you would with any primitives like `+`. However you have extra parenthesis around `(car lst)` and `(car (cdr lst))` which means you expect first element to also be a procedure you call with the second element as it's only argument and then `fn` only get one argument (the result of that if 3, 5 or 2 happens to be procedures) Perhaps you instead wanted `(fn (car lst) (cadr lst))` (I'm using shothand for car+cdr)

Your base case should check both `l` and `(cdr l)` for null since if either one is you are fnished. (Try calling it with `(fn-name + '(5))`). You can use special form `or` to do that like `(or test1 test2)`.

Also notice that `null` is not usually a bound symbol in Scheme. You either need to define it `(define null '())` or use `'()`.

**EDIT** ABout too many results..

Notice that when you have applied the first round withe the first two elements of the list you recurse with a new l starting at the list except the very first element.. That means you then will process `9` and `5` in the next iteration instead of `5` and `8`. To fix that you need to use `cddr` (cdr+cdr) instead of just `cdr`.

Comment: I got it to print (12 14 13 10 6 11), the problem was with my parentheses, which looks like it is appropriately adjusting the values except its returning too many now. Should be (12 13 6). I'm not sure how to handle this...

Comment: Actually I got it, tacked on another cdr at the bottom and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @CSDUDE That's great. It takes a little time getting used to but once you understand you can do `(define (abs x) ((if (< x 0) - +) x))` you'll love the power it brings that got you those errors today..

Comment: Also, even before you come to appreciate the power, you will at least learn that the error "application: not a procedure" usually means you have extra parens. ;)