# Why doesn't scheme allow you to call a function from within another function?

Tags: scheme, lisp

```
(define function1 (lambda(val)
  (if (list? val) 
     (function2 (val))
     ('!list))))
```

When I try the input '(t t t), I get the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (t t t)
  arguments...: [none]
```

I've defined function2 and it works when I call that on its own, but I'm unable to call it within function1.

Comment: I submitted an edit to clean up your code sample to give it better more lisp-y style. I hope it is accepted. I believe that with cleaner style of code your syntax errors are actually easier to spot.

Comment: Have a look at (possible duplicate) [“application: not a procedure” in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `val` is not a function. You should replace `(function2(val))` with `(function2 val)`.

Furthermore `'!list` is also not a function; the else clause of the `if` expression also needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 3):

It is `'!list` and `val` that are not procedures.